# Solve the inequality $\sqrt[3]{1+(3+x)\sqrt{x}+3x} - \sqrt[3]{1-(3+x)\sqrt{x}+3x} > x + a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, nested-radicals

So am trying to solve this inequality, $\sqrt[3]{1+(3+x)\sqrt{x}+3x} - \sqrt[3]{1-(3+x)\sqrt{x}+3x} > x + a$, the problem is of course for values $0<a<1$, I tried working through it multiple times but the solutions i found, which they are $\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-a}}<x<1 $ are the wrong ones when I try wolfram alpha, can anyone show me the right way to do it please?

Comment: How did you go from cube roots to square roots?

Comment: The solution you found makes sense only if the question has a square root nested within the cube root, i.e. you're solving $\sqrt[3]{1+(3+x)\sqrt{x}+3x} - ...$ and so on. Please double check the question.

Comment: @Macavity yeah my bad you are right, i changed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously need $x > 0$ and further have
$$\sqrt[3]{(1+\sqrt x)^3} - \sqrt[3]{(1-\sqrt x)^3} > x+a$$

$\iff  1-a > (\sqrt x - 1)^2 \iff \sqrt{1-a} > |\sqrt x - 1|$

For $x \in (0, 1)$, we have this as
$ \sqrt{1-a} > 1-\sqrt x \implies x > (1-\sqrt{1-a})^2 $

For $x \geqslant 1$, we have this as
$ \sqrt{1-a} > \sqrt x - 1  \implies (1+\sqrt{1-a})^2 > x $

Thus the solution set is $x \in \left((1-\sqrt{1-a})^2, (1 + \sqrt{1-a})^2\right)$.